# Using private DNS

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, cloud

My company has a public cloud at OVH. Each server is a Debian 9 instance. I've configured the servers to be on the same private network and I would like to configure a internal DNS so that the servers query each other with their names.
Basically each server has a public interface with the OVH DNS configured and a private interface where I have configured the internal DNS.
I've configured the internal DNS server with Bind9 and the hosts private interface to query that DNS. /etc/resolv.conf is actually configured with both the public and private DNS and searches for my private domain.
The problem is that when I try to query my private DNS (with nslookup for instance), only the public one answers.

EDIT

I can reach my private DNS using

```
dig -b X.X.X.X mydomain.com
```

with X.X.X.X the IP address of my private interface. I guess the problem comes from my host configuration. It seems that nslookup stops its searches at the first DNS in /etc/resolv.conf even though it does not find the private domain.

EDIT 2

As stated by Lasse Michael Mølgaard in the comments, manually setting the private DNS in the first line of resolv.conf solved the problem. However, that file is automatically modified by the resolvconf program and I need to find a way to make the changes persistent

Comment: You should configure your devices to use the internal DNSs. The external ones should be used only to maintain authority of the domain/site name and such.

Comment: Thanks ! How do I do that ?

Comment: You configure them on each client station (by DHCP if available).

Comment: I only have static addresses configured in /etc/network/interfaces.d/ where I also specified my DNS server and domain. It still doesn't work though, do I have to do something else ? My resolv.conf show my DNS and domain

Comment: You can add your private DNS server as the first line in resolv.conf and on the next line add the public DNS. That way your private DNS will answer first and system will fallback to public DNS if private is offline. *** Beware *** In Ubuntu systems it has a tendency to get overwritten once in a while. I can't remember the right place to update it by heart.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try but my resolv.conf is automatically modified by resolvconf. Also, doesn't it implies that the public DNS isn't available if the private one is ? I will use the private one only for resolving internal network servers so i still need access to the public one